# Is the same a package.json and a composer.json?

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i would like to know if a package.json is the same as a composer.json.
I need to create one file with some content, i required to put it in a package.json file but in the project there is a composer.json already. So can i work in this file or they work diffent?
Thanks

Comment: package.json is for NPM packages. composer.json is for PHP packages. You will need to create a new file.

Answer (score 17):

They are not the same

- package.json is a npm file to keep track of npm packages.
- composer.json is a composer file to keep track of php packages.

Comment: Thanks, so this mean i need to create two different files and there will be no problem between them, right?

Comment: Yes @Álvaro, they are separate and will not conflict

Answer (score 8):

Best difference between **`composer.json`** & **`package.json`** file.

> **`composer.json`**

- Composer is a package manger tool for php.
- composer.json manages the PHP dependencies.
- For Example `composer require fzaninotto/faker`. This command will open and write to the composer.json file and download all the dependencies

> **`package.json`**

- package.json manages the Node dependencies.
- All npm packages contain a file, usually in the project root, called package.json - this file holds various metadata relevant to the project. This file is used to give information to npm that allows it to identify the project as well as handle the project's dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

They are different files. `composer.json` is for [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), a package manager for PHP, whereas `package.json` is for [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/), primarily used together with Node.js.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information you've already been given, about `package.json` being a file to manage Node dependencies, there is another possibility.

Composer also uses a `packages.json` file (note the plural) to define a composer repository. It consists of composer.json objects together with information about where to download the files from. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories

Your question's unclear about what you're trying to do. Whilst you tagged javascript, you don't mention it anywhere in the question itself.